# Firebase Exception DEVELOPMENT_MODE_MISMATCH when using phone number authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been publishing android App that use firebase phone number authentication ,when the app was in the debug mode everything worked fine but in the release mode the phone number authentication throw the following  exception

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [     DEVELOPMENT_MODE_MISMATCH:Non-development mode Verification Proof given in development mode request. ]

The code is

```
String phoneNumber = getPhoneNumber();

loginProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// send verification sms
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber,
        60,
        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        this,
        new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                // when auto verification happens
                // sign-in

                mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(LogInActivity.this, loginListener).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // when the user enter invalid number
                    mPhoneLayout.setError(getString(R.string.wrong_phone_number));
                    mPhoneLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);

                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                    // when free sms limitation is reached
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(final String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {

                showVerificationDialog(verificationId);
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Are you using whitelisted phone numbers by any chance? If so, was the user you are trying to sign in with created with a whitelisted phone number via the admin sdk?

Answer (score 3):

Please check following issue on Github. According to most recent comment, issue is resolved:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/405

I didn't test with latest release yet but firebase throws this error if you try to patch whitelisted phone number with `phoneNumber` as one of the field.